# Finding point parallel to other point

Tags: java, graphics, 3d, point, jogl

I am trying to find out how I can make a race track of 4 units width, I figured I need to find a point parallel to another point, I've read up on this: http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Point-LineDistance3-Dimensional.html

But I can't make much sense out of it, this is how I am making my points currently (part of method):

```
    private List<VectorData> calculateTrack(int trackNr) {  
        Vector trackHeight = new Vector(0d, 0d, 2d);
        //Generate all points
        List<VectorData> points = new ArrayList<>();
        for (double t = 0d; t < 1.00d; t += (1d / SEGMENTS)) {
            Vector pIn, pOut, p0, p1, p2, p3;
            switch (trackNr) {
                case 0:
                    pIn = getPoint(t);
                    pOut = getOuterPoint(t);
                    p0 = pIn.subtract(trackHeight);   //bottom point inside of track
                    p1 = pIn;    //top point inside of track
//                    p2 = p.add(p.cross(p.add(Vector.Z)).normalized().scale(4d));
//                    p3 = p.add(p.cross(p.add(Vector.Z)).normalized().scale(4d)).subtract(trackHeight);
                    p2 = pOut;   //top point outside of track
                    p3 = pOut.subtract(trackHeight);  //bottom point outside of track
                    break;
                case 1:
                    pIn = getCubicBezierPnt(t, controlPointsOTrack[0], controlPointsOTrack[1], controlPointsOTrack[2], controlPointsOTrack[3]);    //bottom point inside
                    pOut = getCubicBezierPnt(t, controlPointsOTrackOutside[0], controlPointsOTrackOutside[1], controlPointsOTrackOutside[2], controlPointsOTrackOutside[3]);
                    p0 = pIn.subtract(trackHeight);   //top point inside
                    p1 = pIn;   //top point inside
//                    p2 = p.add(p.cross(Vector.Z).normalized().scale(4d));   //top point outside
//                    p3 = p.add(p.cross(Vector.Z).normalized().scale(4d)).subtract(trackHeight); //bottom point outside
                    p2 = pOut;
                    p3 = pOut.subtract(trackHeight);
                    break;
                default:
                    throw new IllegalArgumentException("RaceTrack.calculateTrack: Unknown trackNr: trackNr = " + trackNr);
            }


            VectorData[] pArray = { new VectorData(p0, null), new VectorData(p1, null), new VectorData(p2, null), new VectorData(p3, null) };
            points.addAll(Arrays.asList(pArray));
        }
```

As you can see I 'cheat' now by using `getPoint(t)` and `getOuterPoint(t)`, but firstly I don't want to do it, and secondly that does not work with bezier curves anymore.

So could anyone guide me how I would get a point perpendicular to another point?

Effectively replacing the following code:

```
/**
 * Returns the position of the curve at 0 <= {@code t} <= 1.
 */
public Vector getPoint(double t) {
    return new Vector(
            10 * Math.cos(2 * Math.PI * t),
            14 * Math.sin(2 * Math.PI * t),
            1d
            );
}

public Vector getOuterPoint(double t) {
    return new Vector(
            (10 + 4) * Math.cos(2 * Math.PI * t),
            (14 + 4) * Math.sin(2 * Math.PI * t),
            1d
            );
}
```

My proposed solution:

```
        Vector vDelta = getPointPerTrackNr(trackNr, (t + (1d / SEGMENTS)) % 1.00d).subtract(pIn);
        Vector vWidth = new Vector(
                        (vDelta.x() * Math.cos(Math.toRadians(270))) - (vDelta.y() * Math.sin(Math.toRadians(270))),
                        (vDelta.x() * Math.sin(Math.toRadians(270))) + (vDelta.y() * Math.cos(Math.toRadians(270))),
                        vDelta.z()
                ).normalized().scale(RobotRace.NUM_ROBOTS * 1d);
```

First I calculate `vDelta`, which is the distance between the current track segment at `t`, to the next track segments, for example `t + 0.01d`.

Then I calcualte the `vWidth` by taking `vDelta`, rotating it by 270 degrees, then normalizing it, and then scaling it with the width, in this case being `RobotRace.NUM_ROBOTS * 1d`.

Comment: Do your question mean that you need to find a curve (or polygonal chain) that has everywhere the same distance to a given curve (polygonal chain)?

Comment: @divanov Yes, I'll update the OP with a working example of mine now, though I'm sure there are better methods.

Comment: Points cannot be parallel, only lines (curves) and line segments can - this is highly confusing.